# How to export to XML format from DJango SQLIte

Tags: python, html, django

I have a table of datasets in a django template like so:

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}

{% block title %}Catalogs{% endblock %}

{% block content %}

<table class="table table-bordered" id="tblData"> 
    <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>DatasetName</th>
                <th>Type</th>
                <th>Classification</th>
                <th>OriginalSource</th>
                <th>OriginalOwner</th>
                <th>YearOfOrigin</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
</table> 

{% for catalog in object_list %} 

<div class="container"> 
    <table class="table table-bordered">
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>
                <form>
                    <p><input type="checkbox" id="agreeCheckbox" name="agreeCheckbox" value="agreeCheckbox" onchange="toggleLink(this);"></p>
                </form>
                </td>
                <td>{{ catalog.DatasetName }}</td>
                <td>{{ catalog.Type }}</td>
                <td>{{ catalog.Classification }}</td>
                <td>{{ catalog.OriginalSource }}</td>
                <td>{{ catalog.OriginalOwner }}</td>
                <td>{{ catalog.YearOfOrigin }}</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>


<div class="card-footer text-center text-muted"> 
    <a href="{% url 'catalog_edit' catalog.pk %}" id="agreeLink1" style="display:none;">Update</a> |
    <a href="{% url 'catalog_delete' catalog.pk %}" id="agreeLink2" style="display:none;">Delete</a> |
    <a href="{% url 'export_to_xml' %}" id="agreeLink3" style="display:none;">Export to XML</a>
</div> 

{% endfor %}
{% endblock content %}

I have implemented the check box functionality for each of the rows of the table like so:

function toggleLink(checkBox)
{
    var link1 = document.getElementById("agreeLink1");
    var link2 = document.getElementById("agreeLink2");
    var link3 = document.getElementById("agreeLink3");

    if (checkBox.checked)
    {
        link1.style.display = "inline";
        link2.style.display = "inline";
        link3.style.display = "inline";
    }
    else {
        link1.style.display = "none";
        link2.style.display = "none";
        link3.style.display = "none";
    }
}
```

I have a model of datasets like so:

```
class Catalog(models.Model): 
    DatasetName = models.CharField(max_length=280)
    Type = models.CharField(max_length=280)
    Classification = models.CharField(max_length=280)
    OriginalSource = models.CharField(max_length=280)
    OriginalOwner = models.CharField(max_length=280)
    YearofOrigin = models.IntegerField(default=0)

    def get_absolute_url(self): 
        return reverse('catalog_detail', args=[str(self.id)])

    def __str__(self): 
        return self.DatasetName
```

I have implemented a serializerin the view.py file that exports all the datasets like so:

```
def export_to_xml(request):
from django.core import serializers
data = serializers.serialize("xml", Catalog.objects.all())
from django.core.files import File
f = open('catalogs.xml', 'w')
myfile = File(f)
myfile.write(data)
myfile.close()
return HttpResponse("All done!")
```

I want to export only those datasets whose checkboxes have been checked. Each dataset is written as a table with a checkbox. I want to export in XML format only those datasets whose checkbox has been checked. Does anybody have any idea on how to do it?

Answer (score 1):

Something like this.
template

```
<form>
<p><input type="checkbox" id="agreeCheckbox" name="agreeCheckbox" value="{{catalog.id}}" onchange="toggleLink(this);"></p>
</form>
```

views.py

```
def export_to_xml(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        #gives list of id of inputs 
        list_of_input_ids=request.POST.getlist('agreeCheckbox')
    from django.core import serializers
    data = serializers.serialize("xml", Catalog.objects.filter(id__in=list_of_input_ids))
    from django.core.files import File
    f = open('catalogs.xml', 'w')
    myfile = File(f)
    myfile.write(data)
    myfile.close()
    return HttpResponse("All done!")
```